# Как сделать парсер для языка программирования?

Tags: python, парсер

Привет! Я сделал лексер который принимает строку `a:=1+3`, и выдает
`[('ID', 'a'), ('ASSIGN', ':='), ('INT', '1'), ('OP', '+'), ('INT', '3')]`.

Как можно
сделать парсер чтобы он вычислял выражение и запоминал переменную?

Comment: Используйте `numexpr`

Comment: например посмотрите в сторону "обратная польская запись". Или так назначьте операторам приоритеты, далее по приоритетам берите параметры, вычисляйте, результат подставляйте вместо вычисленного, что бы стоящие рядом менее приоритетные операторы взяли это как параметр.

Comment: хотя конкретный пример, легко можно посчитать, общая теория не одну книгу занимает.

Comment: Я думаю можно целый язык программирования на 'обратной польской нотации' сделать ,так ведь?

Comment: Да, можно. В калькуляторах типа [МК-61](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Электроника_МК-61) (до сих пор у меня на антресолях лежит) такой язык и был.

Comment: Один из самых простых способов - использовать [рекурсивный нисходящий парсер](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) (на русском статья куцая). Примеров [реализации](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Реализации_алгоритмов/Метод_рекурсивного_спуска) в сети полно; думаю, не составит труда перевести на нужный язык.